# If $a,b < p$, then $p \nmid ab$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that if there two positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that they are less than a prime number $p$, then the product  $ab$ will not be divisible by $p$.

I know there must be multiple proofs involved to solve this one, but can you guys help me out? I don't even know like where to start!!

Comment: What do you already know, Euclid's Lemma, Bezout identity, gcd laws, fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Answer (score 6):

$p|ab \iff p|a$ or $p|b$.  However, since $a,b < p$, then $p \nmid a$ and $p \nmid b$.  Hence, $p \nmid ab$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose for contradiction that $ p | ab $, then by euclids theorem,  $ p | a $ or $p | b $. Suppose $a | p $ then there exists $k > 0$ such that $a = pk $ but $pk \geq p $. Hence $ a \geq p $. Similarly for $b$. This is a contradiction and the problem is solved.

Comment: Good save with the edit there. +1

Comment: What do you mean by "Euclid's theorem"?

Comment: I think it is euclid lemma ?

Comment: What theorem are you using, i.e. what is its statement?

Answer (score 0):

you can write both $a$ and $b$ as a product of prime numbers, that is

$a= a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4...$

and

$b= b_1 b_2 b_3 b_4...$

where the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are prime numbers

if $a<p$ that implies that $a_i <p$ for all $i$, likewise $b<p$ implies that $b_i <p$ for all $i$

so

$ab=a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4...  b_1 b_2 b_3 b_4...$

and since $a_i <p$ and $b_i <p$, $p$ does not divide $ab$